# Word for "ability to explain"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> I want to test your ability to explain.

I was thinking *present*, as in *your ability to present* — being able to give a good presentation.

That's the only choice I can think of, but I feel there's a better one. I googled it, but only received topics about improving how to explain thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary.com defines...

> [**cogent**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cogent) *- convincing or believable by virtue of forcible, clear, or incisive presentation; telling.*

It's often applied to an *argument* (verbal presentation in favour of a particular concept) but it's also commonly used of *people* who are good at presenting arguments, explanations, etc.

Comment: I don't believe an adjective answers the question.

Comment: @stevesliva Why not? The question is: a word for ability... Intelligent is an adjective (having or showing the ability to acquire and apply knowledge and skills); empathic is also an adjective (showing an ability to share the feelings of another). (definitions from ODO). I quite like this word.

Comment: @Lucky One doesn't test or evaluate an adjective.  And perhaps I nitpick the answer because I think *cogent* really isn't used to describe people all that often.  It's far more often used to describe arguments.

Comment: @stevesliva: I think anyone who can't transparently apply the regular transformation to get from my adjectival *cogent* to hrexen's noun form *cogency* should probably be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), so that's something of a non-issue. I did intend to flag up that [a cogent **argument**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+cogent+argument%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is far more common than [a cogent **speaker**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+cogent+speaker%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) though - but perhaps I didn't express that very well.

Comment: *Cogency* is so rare that it's a terrible word to use if one want to be cogent, which might have been why it wasn't your answer in the first place.  Opinions on connotation and use are germane here.  The number of answers offered because the dictionary suggest they're fitting is depressing.

Comment: Person with didactic skill

Comment: @rogermue: I suppose everyone will have their own associations for many words in this general area. "Brainwashing" would be putting it a bit strong, but my somewhat jaundiced view of "didactic" elements (in a movie, say) is that they're (often covertly) intended to *instruct, train*. So to me a *didactic* teacher might train a class parrot-fashion, whereas a *cogent* lecture would normally impart true understanding through explication.

Comment: @stevesliva "The duration of the interview may depend upon **how cogent** and convincing you are in reply to the first question" from: How to Present at Meetings, edited by George M. Hall, John Wiley & Sons, 2013 - usage of cogent to describe people and their presentation isn't unheard of :-)

Comment: @Lucky, yes.  But it's sort of like "prove to me that you're coherent." As if to assume one's *always* coherent, when coherent is a description of a person at one point in time. It's not describing the skill (say, precise articulation of complex concepts or precise elocution) but the effect of it.  Were you cogent? Yes. Why? Because you have good communication skills.  It's a impermanent adjective versus a descriptive, permanent adjective. Good public speakers may be incoherent sometimes, even if they have the skill.  Anyways, blahblahblah.

Answer (score 3):

> **cogency** - the capacity to persuade

[merriam-webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/cogency)

Comment: +1 haha - why not indeed, if OP insists on a *noun?* :)

Comment: Here's another good one: [**lucidity**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lucidity) *the quality of being easily understood, completely intelligible, or comprehensible*.

Comment: Or for a *verb*, [**explicate**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/explicate) *- to make plain or clear; explain; interpret*

Answer (score 0):

> **Communicate** -  to give information about (something) to someone by speaking, writing, moving your hands, etc.

[Merriam Webster Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/communicate)

In your example: 'I want to test your ability to communicate' or perhaps 'I want to test your communication'.

Comment: I would go by ELUCIDATE.

Answer (score 0):

A person asking, "Ability to express oneself in an appropriate manner" was redirected to this thread, but I don't think it's the same question.

I initially thought eloquent or articulate, but upon further thought, I suspect what they are asking for (probably for writing a job description) is the ability to communicate decorously.